# required field validator not working with html editor

Tags: requiredfieldvalidator, html-editor

I have a text box using cc1:Editor and when I place a required field validator on it, it displays as soon as the page loads.  How can I hide the error and allow it to display only if the html editor box is empty?

```
<code><cc1:Editor ID="txtDescription" Width="500px" Height="525px" 
 runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" /></code>
<code>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDescription" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtDescription"  
ErrorMessage="Must include Description" Font-Bold="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</code>

<code><asp:Button ID="SubmitBtn" runat="server" 
Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" class="form-td" Height="30px" />
```

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeypress = keyhandler;
    function keyhandler(e) {
      Key = window.event.keyCode; if (Key == 13) {
        var obj = document.getElementById('<%=SubmitBtn.ClientID%>');
        obj.focus();
        obj.click();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to validate on a button click/postback or page load ?

Comment: No because I'm using onclick to process this page.

Comment: On click of what ? 'onclick' client side or is it server side?

Comment: I added the submit button onclick event so you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform custom validation on your submit button client side & server side validation on your postback event thus removing required field validator. Check following example:
On your aspx page

```
<p>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="javascript:return ValidateEditor();" 
        ValidationGroup="myGroup" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <br />
</p>
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
<cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateEditor() {
        var txtEditor = $find('<%=Editor1.ClientID %>');
        if (txtEditor.get_content() == null || txtEditor.get_content() == '') {
            alert('Text cannot be empty');
            document.getElementById('<%=lblMessage.ClientID %>').innerHTML='Text cannot be empty';
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
</script>
```

On server side

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Editor1.Content.ToString()))
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Text cannot be empty";
        }
        else
        {
            // Do your work here
        }
```

Comment: None of this is working, is there another way to do this?  It seems that on load this field is appearing to be empty and this is why the error is displayed.  How can I get around this?  Please someone help